# Multiple Rows In Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have spent a large part of the day browsing this website and many others and have yet to find a solution for my problem.

I am currently trying to run a query on MS Access that will pull the following columns:

The problem is I need the milestone to be the **most recent** milestone. The due_date corresponds to this milestone.

Each milestone is entered with an autonumber ID and I have been trying to use this ID to pull together my query.

This query:

```
SELECT E.EID, E.[CN], E.[AN], E.Status, MAX(M.ID) AS Milestone_ID
FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M, [PP Engagements] AS E, [Pilot Milestone] AS D
WHERE E.EID=M.EID
GROUP BY M.EID, E.EID, E.[CN], E.[AN], E.Status, E.[Estimated Hours]
```

Leaves me with the most recent Milestone ID for each EID. However, if I add Due_Dates:

```
SELECT E.EID, E.[CN], E.[AN], E.Status, MAX(M.ID) AS Milestone_ID, M.(Due Date)
FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M, [PP Engagements] AS E, [Pilot Milestone] AS D
WHERE E.EID=M.EID
GROUP BY M.EID, E.EID, E.[CN], E.[AN], E.Status, E.[Estimated Hours], M.(Due Date)
```

I receive two additional records for EID 30. These are the **only** two records with due dates and **neither** reflect the most recent Milestone ID.

Also each EID has multiple Milestones, thus if I enter the Milestone description in my query the same way as I did with Due Date I encounter a similar problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**REVISED**

The following query gives me results for my due_dates without any duplicates as I just tested in MS Access 2007. However, the query pulls the most recent date regardless if it is from the most recent milestone.

```
SELECT E.EID, E.[Client Name], E.[Audit Name], E.Status, MAX(M.ID) AS Milestone_ID, (
SELECT MAX ([Due Date]) FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M2 WHERE M2.EID = M.EID) AS Due_Date
FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M, [Potential Pilot Engagements] AS E
WHERE E.EID=M.EID
GROUP BY M.EID, E.EID, E.[Client Name], E.[Audit Name], E.Status, E.[Estimated Hours]
```

Also, I am unsure how to add the Milestone description to the result without either adding it as part of the aggregate function (resulting in duplicates) or adding it in a subquery that results in more than one record and an error

```
SELECT E.EID, E.[Client Name], E.[Audit Name], E.Status, MAX(M.ID) AS Milestone_ID, (
SELECT MAX ([Due Date]) FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M2 WHERE M2.EID = M.EID) AS Due_Date, (
SELECT (Milestone) FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M3 WHERE M3.EID = M.EID) AS Milestone
FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M, [Potential Pilot Engagements] AS E
WHERE E.EID=M.EID
GROUP BY M.EID, E.EID, E.[Client Name], E.[Audit Name], E.Status, E.[Estimated Hours]
```

Comment: Unless you add a condition, you're getting a cartesian product due to the `D` reference to `Pilot Milestone`.  This is invisible due to the `GROUP BY`, but is costing you in performance time (especially as you're not using the reference).  This is why you should always explicitly qualify your joins, and not use the implicit (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax.  Showing source tables/sample data and desired results may help us help you, as will the version of Access you're using.  You also shouldn't need to group by both `M.EID` _and_ `E.EID`, given they'll be identical for the given row.

Comment: Thank you, I accidently wrote down the query on here while looking at the wrong parts of my notepad resulting in the Pilot Milestone AS D mistake. I am just copying from Access (2007) now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the list of the most recent Milestone_IDs along with the most recent Due Date for each Milestone_ID

```
SELECT 
    E.[EID], E.[CN], E.[AN], M.[Milestone], E.[Status], MAX(M.[ID]) AS Milestone_ID, (
        SELECT MAX([Due Date]) FROM [Pilot Milestone] AS M2 WHERE M2.[ID]=MAX(M.[ID]) AND M2.[EID]=M.[EID]
        ) as Due_Date
FROM 
    [Pilot Milestone] AS M
    INNER JOIN [PP Engagements] AS E ON E.[EID]=M.[EID]
GROUP BY E.[EID], E.[CN], E.[AN], M.[Milestone], E.[Status]
```

Comment: No, M.ID gives me the most recent Milestone. The problem is I have to include M.Milestone in my query. So while the first query I listed above accurately gives me a reference to the most recent milestone through the Milestone ID, if I add Milestone to my SELECT statement it pulls up every milestone for each EID, while I only need the most recent.

Comment: @Ianclark I edited my answer based on your comment.  Please retest.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to write the query from that in order to pull due dates without any duplicates. One problem is, however, that if a less current milestone has a later due_date it will pull the later, inaccurate, date. Do you by chance know how I would go about resolving this and/or being able to pull the milestone description as well? I revised my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ianclark, changed the query based on your last comment